# Number inputs as raster calculator variables in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

How can i use input numbers as variables in any of the raster calculator algorithms in QGIS through the modeler? One very simple example of that would be a model that allows me to divide raster cell values by an input number:

[image: model example]

The thing is: none of the raster calculator algorithms lets me pick the number input as a variable. Is that not possible solely through the application's modeler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can combine input numbers with the formula from the GUI modeler. I tried testing it and didn't seem to like it.

An alternative could be to create a **custom script** which, when executed, can look like the exact same interface as when you run a model. The difference here is that you have to write out the code (you can find more information here: [Writing new Processing algorithms as python scripts](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html)).

To create such a script, go to:

```py
Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script
```

Then copy/paste the following:

```py
##Example=name
##Input_Raster=raster
##Number=number 1

processing.runandload("saga:rastercalculator", Input_Raster, '', 'a / ' + str(Number), False, 7, None)
```

Save the script and run it from the *Processing Toolbox*:

[image: Executing script]

*Note: I receive errors when trying to save it directly to a directory. To avoid this, the code saves and loads the output as a temporary layer. You can then save this layer manually.*

---

---

Essentially, you define various parameters at the beginning of the script (i.e. name of script, input layer, input number). The last line calls the **Raster Calculator** function from the *Processing* plugin where you can define the required parameters. You can find what parameters are required from the **Python Console** (from the menubar `Plugins > Python Console`) and type:

```py
import processing
processing.alghelp("saga:rastercalculator")
```

You should receive:

```py
Python Console 
Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
>>> import processing
>>> processing.alghelp("saga:rastercalculator")
ALGORITHM: Raster calculator
    GRIDS <ParameterRaster>
    XGRIDS <ParameterMultipleInput>
    FORMULA <ParameterString>
    USE_NODATA <ParameterBoolean>
    TYPE <ParameterSelection>
    RESULT <OutputRaster>

TYPE(Output Data Type)
    0 - [0] bit
    1 - [1] unsigned 1 byte integer
    2 - [2] signed 1 byte integer
    3 - [3] unsigned 2 byte integer
    4 - [4] signed 2 byte integer
    5 - [5] unsigned 4 byte integer
    6 - [6] signed 4 byte integer
    7 - [7] 4 byte floating point number
    8 - [8] 8 byte floating point number
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Besides helping with the question this helped me come up with solutions for some other problems i had.

Comment: @pdebem - Most welcome, glad it was helpful :)

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328261/using-variable-in-graphical-modeler-for-raster-calculation-qgis-3-8