# Calling gdalogr:rasterize algorithm in python console in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, rasterization

I'm trying to rasterize a simple line-vector layer. I can do it by using QGIS GUI, but I want to do the same with python console.
Unfortunately it always gives back an "Error: Wrong number of parameters" or "Wrong parameter:___".

Call like processing.alglist('gdalogr:rasterize') gives the shown list of parameters, where for many of them there is no further explanation what they are and how to set them. I'm using QGIS 2.16.1.

Has anyone made a successful call for this algorithm?

ALGORITHM: Rasterize (vector to raster)

```
INPUT <ParameterVector>
FIELD <parameters from INPUT>
DIMENSIONS <ParameterSelection>
WIDTH <ParameterNumber>
HEIGHT <ParameterNumber>
RAST_EXT <ParameterExtent>
TFW <ParameterBoolean>
RTYPE <ParameterSelection>
NO_DATA <ParameterString>
COMPRESS <ParameterSelection>
JPEGCOMPRESSION <ParameterNumber>
ZLEVEL <ParameterNumber>
PREDICTOR <ParameterNumber>
TILED <ParameterBoolean>
BIGTIFF <ParameterSelection>
EXTRA <ParameterString>
OUTPUT <OutputRaster>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Borrowing* [@Germán Carrillo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/4972/germ%c3%a1n-carrillo) method of calling processing algorithms using a dictionary (as described in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209449/how-to-make-processing-algorithms-use-default-parameter-values-in-qgis-2-14)), you could use something like:

```
import processing

input = iface.activeLayer()
layer = QgsVectorLayer(input.source(),"polygon","ogr")

extent = layer.extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

processing.runalg("gdalogr:rasterize",
                   {"INPUT":layer,
                   "FIELD":"d",
                   "DIMENSIONS":0,
                   "WIDTH":1,
                   "HEIGHT":1,
                   "RAST_EXT":"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
                   "TFW":1,
                   "RTYPE":5,
                   "NO_DATA":0,
                   "COMPRESS":0,
                   "JPEGCOMPRESSION":1,
                   "ZLEVEL":1,
                   "PREDICTOR":1,
                   "TILED":False,
                   "BIGTIFF":2,
                   "EXTRA": '',
                   "OUTPUT":"C:/Users/You/Desktop/result.tif"})
```

---

You could have a look at the [rasterize.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/rasterize.py) script where some of the paramters are defined in the comments inside the `defineCharacteristics()` function.

Comment: It is still missing 2 parameters: RAST_EXT <ParameterExtent> and EXTRA <ParameterString>. Is there any explanation for these two?
I was looking at the links you provided, but I'm still quite unfamiliar how to read (understand) them...Tnx

Comment: @Pandza - Apologies, edited the post so it should run now =)

Comment: Tnx a lot. Now I can call this function and get a raster. For my simple line result raster looks like "background pixels-no data" and "line pixels-value is 2". Can I somehow set it to get 0 for background and 1 for line pixels?

Comment: @Pandza - Most welcome, glad it worked! Hmm, I would probably use the **SAGA Raster Calculator** and use an `if else` statement like: `ifelse((a=2),1,0)`.

Comment: Yes, **Raster calculator** was also my idea in case there is no option to set it straight away. Regards