# How to pass an extent parameter to a Processing algorithm in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I want to convert a point shapefile to a raster with the same extent and resolution as an input raster using the algorithm saga:shapestogrid.
When I run this code:

```
##Sampled_trees=vector
##Input_field= field Sampled_trees
##Elevation_model=raster

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

inputTrees= processing.getObject(Sampled_trees)
inputField = inputTrees.fieldNameIndex(Input_field)
dem = processing.getObject(Elevation_model)

result = processing.runalg('saga:shapestogrid', inputTrees, Input_field, 0, 0, 4, dem.extent(),  dem.rasterUnitsPerPixelX(), path)
```

I get the error: Error: Wrong parameter value: qgis._core.QgsRectangle object at 0x0000000019F287B8

If I add or remove any parameter, the error will be Error: Wrong number of parameters.

The [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/grid_gridding/shapestogrid.html) gives the following syntax: 
processing.runalg('saga:shapestogrid', input, field, multiple, line_type, grid_type, output_extent, user_size, user_grid)

How should I define the output_extent parameter to make the algorithm to run?

Comment: Interesting, don't have this tool available in QGIS 2.16.1 but anyway, try defining the extent instead like in an example I posted [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212645/how-to-make-qgis-processing-algorithms-use-default-parameter/212646#212646) which defines the `xmin, xmax...` etc and then calling this in your parameter as `"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you, Processing could just accept a `QgsRectangle` and make our lives easier.

However, Processing needs the extent in this way (see http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/extents.html):

```
"Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax"
```

So, you can just pass that argument as:

```
extent = "%s,%s,%s,%s" % ( dem.extent.xMinimum(), dem.extent.xMaximum(), dem.extent.yMinimum(), dem.extent.yMaximum() )

result = processing.runalg('saga:shapestogrid', inputTrees, Input_field, 0, 0, 4, extent,  dem.rasterUnitsPerPixelX(), path)
```

Comment: Do you mind if I edit the title to "How to pass an extent parameter to a Processing algorithm in PyQGIS"? I think that way it would be more useful to other users, while still reflecting you're original intention.

Comment: It would be a good idea.