# SAGA Raster Calculator processing script give error "name 'Rasterout' is not defined"

Tags: qgis-processing, raster-calculator, saga, nameerror

I am trying to build a custom script using things I have learned from this post: [Number inputs as raster calculator variables in QGIS Modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206004/number-inputs-as-raster-calculator-variables-in-qgis-modeler)

This is my script so far:

```
##Maechtigkeit unterhalb einer Hoehe=name
##Input_Raster=raster
##Hoehe = string 28.65
##Rasterout = output raster

outputs_SAGARASTERCALCULATOR_1=processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', Input_Raster,[],'a - Hoehe',0,False,7,Rasterout)
```

But I always get the error

> name 'Rasterout' is not defined See log for more details

When omitting the Rasterout parameter and type `None` instead, it seems to run through but doesn't give me the temporary layer I need? So nothing happens really.

Is there another option for the last parameter? I tried consulting the SAGA documentation but it doesn't yield the information I need.

Also I need that output raster to do more raster calculations on.

How would I be writing that? Can I just rewrite the line:

`outputs_SAGARASTERCALCULATOR_1=processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', Input_Raster,[],'a - Hoehe',0,False,7,Rasterout)`

and use Rasterout instead of Input_Raster? And define a new Output variable'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Avoid** using spaces when defining parameters (excluding the name) as this can cause errors:

```
##Maechtigkeit unterhalb einer Hoehe=name
##Input_Raster=raster
##Hoehe=string 28.65
##Rasterout=output raster
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am confused; which spaces do you mean? "output raster" has a required space without which this parameter will not be available the user. https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html

Comment: @S.Kuske - I meant when you give a name to a parameter. So anything to the left of the `=` sign should not contain any white spaces. E.g. `##Input Raster=raster` will not work; `##Input_Raster=raster` will work.

Comment: Alright thanks. The original error went away after deleting all the spaces. No I am getting a - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details - Error. In both cases, when I want to save it to a file in a directory or leaving it blank and supposedly creating a temporary file, which is actually what I need when trying to move on from here.

Comment: @S.Kuske - I think you should ask this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as StackExchange has a policy of one post per question :)